# Multi check box with multiple radio buttons in angular2?

Tags: json, angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I have a checkbox (a).that checkbox having more two dependency checkbox(b and c)  . With the each checkbox I have 4 radio button respectively in disable state. If I check a, then b and c respectively going to be checked and with that , the radio radio buttons of all checked checkboxes should be enable.

I have completed the checkbox checked section but I am getting problem with enable and disable section of radio buttons.

**My Json** is like

```
public permissionList =   
 [
    {
    "catagoryname": "Business Settings",
    "permission": [
      {
      "permissionname": "Create",
      "ischecked": false,
      "permissionid": 2,
      "depedency": [{
        "depedencyId": 1
      }, {
        "depedencyId": 3
      }],
      "relation": {
        "isActive":true,
        "other": false
      }
    },
      {
      "permissionname": "Edit",
      "ischecked": false,
      "permissionid": 3,
      "depedency": [{
        "depedencyId": 1
      }],
      "relation": {
        "isActive":true,
        "other": false
      }
  },
       {
      "permissionname": "Delete",
      "ischecked": false,
      "permissionid": 4,
      "depedency": [{
        "depedencyId": 1
      }],
        "relation": {
          "isActive":true,
          "other": false
        }
      },
      {
      "permissionname": "View",
      "ischecked": false,
      "permissionid": 1,
        "relation": {
          "isActive":true,
          "other": false
        }
      }]
  },
  {
    "catagoryname": "Panic Settings",
    "permission": [
      {
      "permissionname": "Create Panic",
      "ischecked": false,
      "permissionid": 6,
      "depedency": [{
        "depedencyId": 7
      }, {
        "depedencyId": 5
      }],
        "relation": {
          "isActive":true,
          "other": false
        }
      },
      {
      "permissionname": "Edit Panic",
      "ischecked": false,
      "permissionid": 7,
      "depedency": [{
        "depedencyId": 5
      }],
        "relation": {
          "isActive":true,
          "other": false
         }
      },
      {
      "permissionname": "Delete Panic",
      "ischecked": false,
      "permissionid": 8,
      "depedency": [{
        "depedencyId": 5
      }],
        "relation": {
          "isActive":true,
          "other": false
        }
      },
      {
      "permissionname": "View Panic",
      "ischecked": false,
      "permissionid": 5,
        "relation": {
          "isActive":true,
          "other": false
        }
      }]
  }];
```

and my view and remaing code you can see the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/TaQxU3f9x1RTl2Mmie2N?p=preview).

As I am new to angular 2 , I am not understanding what should I do in this case.Please help me to overcome from this problem.

Comment: I have tried you code on Plunkr it runs perfectly and exactly how I would want it to but the same on the local environment of Angular 2 Quickstart does not work.

It is only disabling the first radio button and not the full group on load..

Answer (score 1):

use `[disabled]` to controll whether the radio buttons should be disabled or not.

I have add it to the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/WZTMzcS3zVcel9rZquaa?p=preview), check it.

Comment: I tried but why I don't it's not working for me, Is there any other solution, only one radio button per row is disabling,

Comment: @Runali sorry, i don't understand what you want now. maybe we could chat here. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137520/angular2-disabled-expression

Comment: I don't have enough reputation points to chat, In my application it only disabling the one radio button per row

Comment: @Runali ok, so now what's the problem? maybe you should post the detail at your question or here.

Comment: I am understanding  what is the problem , I post my entire code on plunker, nothing else I am doing apart from that

Comment: from you question, i get that you want to change the radios' status according to the checkbox's check status of the row. is it all right? or maybe i misunderstood?

Comment: @Runali sorry, can you explain the difference between 'what you actually want' and  the plunker i have made please?